# How to render object collection as editable(checkboxes) list view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

First, I'd like to say that I did a lot of researches, tried many ways but none of it worked. I'd like to avoid:

- writing my own model binder
- packing form into json
- reading directly from FormCollection object

My model class looks like that:

```
public class ListViewModel
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public bool IsChecked { get; set; }        
    }
```

I'm passing it to the view as a IEnumerable collection. 
I'm trying to have all the form data packed into IEnumerable, like here

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Authorize(Roles = "User")]
    public ActionResult EditVisitLists(List<ListViewModel> model)
    {            
        //...
    }
```

Unfortunately, my every attemp fails, I'm receiving null as a model (probably model binder doesn't recognize the form the way I'd like it to)

Here is my latest attemp:

```
@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(m => item.Name)
        </td>
        <td>                
            @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => item.IsChecked, new { id = "[" + item.Id + "].Name" })
            @Html.HiddenFor(m => item.Name)
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a `for` loop instead of a `foreach` to get correct binding

```
@for (var i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++) {
   @Html.Displayfor(m => Model[i].Name

   @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => Model[i].IsChecked)
   @Html.HiddenFor(m => Model[i].Name)
}
```

Look at the html generated, you will now have different `name` and `id` attributes, which should bind fine.